# Very Slow DSL (ethernet) speed [New Interesting Update]

Tags: linux, security, speed, network-adapter, opensuse

Very Interesting and Important Update: Due to some reason I *just* thought to do a complete new setup and this time I decided to *again* have openSUSE plus Ubuntu. So I first reinstall Lubuntu and then I installed OpenSUSE 12.2 (64 bit).

Now, my DSL speed is working very normal and fine on openSUSE. So this is very scary.

Is it possible for any operating system to manipulate my NIC so that it will work fine only on that operating system and not on another os?

Regarding positive thinking and not being paranoid, what is it that makes *only* openSUSE to get my NIC to work at normal speed but Ubuntu can not do it?  Not even fedora?  Not even Linux mint?  What all these OS are lacking that enables openSUSE to work great?

---

This was my original question posted here:

I 'was' on opensuse 12.2 when my dsl speed was normal. Yesterday I switched from opensuse to Ubuntu 12.04 and speed decreased. It came to range of 7-10-13-20-25-kbps. Then I switch to linux mint, and then to fedora. Still slow speed. When I was in Ubuntu I disabled ipv6 but still no luck.

Now I am in fedora but this time with different ISP. And still I am getting very slow sped.
So my guess is this is nothing to do with os. What can be wrong?

Is this problem of NIC?  Does NIC speed decreases over time?  Does NIC life ends over time as with keyboard or mouse?

All the os I used are 64 bit and my laptop is Compaq Presario A965Tu Intel Centrino DUal Core.

Interesting thing to notice is I get normal speed while downloading torrent inside torrent client software. This slow speed issue applied to download from any web browser or installing software using terminal.

Comment: Are you getting dropped packets? Run something like `ping -c 100 google.com` and look at the packet loss.

Comment: @tjameson --- google.com ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 87 received, 13% packet loss, time 99186ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.077/5.896/196.787/20.587 ms

Comment: Yes I am getting packate loss in each ping. First time I tried I got 13%, second time 2% and third time 6% @tjameson

Comment: I had a problem similar to this that was related to MTU on my netbook. `ifconfig eth mtu 1000` made it better, but this might not be the same thing. Compare settings from `ip` in both opensuse and lubuntu and see if there's anything different.

Answer (score 2):

- Test your speed:   `wget --output-document=/dev/null
  http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip`
- Check for errors: `ethtool -S eth0`
- Check if you are running in half duplex: `ethtool eth0`
- Check for packet loss `mtr google.com`

It can be tricky telling the difference between ICMP de-prioritzation and packet loss, *Rule of thumb* is real packet loss doesn't go away on later hops.

**Edit:** ICMP is the protocol that runs Ping, Traceroute & MTR.  Traceroute & MTR work by pinging each router along a path.  Routers are just specialized computers, they have a certain amount of CPU & RAM power available.

When a router has high CPU utilization it priozities packets going **through** the router over ones going **to** the router, this *de-prioritizing* of ICMP, leads to *deceptively higher latency* when you ping that router rather than ping an upstream device (e.g. google.com)

Comment: 1. While trying first suggestion wget --output-documet i got speed in range of 4 to 8 K/s. That is too much slow.                                 

2. ethtool -S eth0 gives this:
sudo ethtool -S eth0
NIC statistics:
     early_rx: 0
     tx_buf_mapped: 0
     tx_timeouts: 0
     rx_lost_in_ring: 0

3. ethtool eth0 give this output http://paste.ubuntu.com/1382689/

4. For mtr google.com this is the output http://imagebin.org/237029

Comment: What is icmp de-prioritization @JamesBarnett

Comment: @Abhijit - What about "CRC errors" from ethtool? Check MTR a few different times, if you keep seeing packet loss then there is some bad hardware somewhere.

First I'd try to swap out the ethernet cable you are using, then try a USB wired NIC with a known good cable.

Comment: I dont get any CRC errors. Whats the ethtool syntax to get crc errors? Alos is bios poweron password has anything to do with this? becuase I have set bios poweron and admin password and after that this issue arise. @JamesBarnett

Comment: CRC errors are shown in ethtool -S, here's an example, they are listed under " rx_crc_errors: 0"

http://itrcp.com/blog/learn/how-to-troubleshoot-nic-in-linux-command-line.html